# How to determine the subnet mask and network interface card from remote SSH login?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, network-programming, aix

In a separate question (link below), it was suggested that I obtain the network interface card number and subnet mask from a remote SSH login, rather than prompting the user for it. All I have is the IP address of my remote host. I need to obtain the subnet mask to determine if the remote and local host are on the same subnet, and the interface card number to set up and configure a virtual IP for aliasing purposes.

Could someone suggest how I might be able to parse out the necessary information and return it to my shell script that initiates the remote ssh connection? My target hosts have Linux or AIX as the operating system. I am familiar with the netstat function, but I'm not sure if parsing information from this is valid, or if there is a better way to get what I need that will work for both Linux and AIX operating systems.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

[How to return from shell 'read' command passed in expect script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244608/how-to-return-from-shell-read-command-passed-in-expect-script?noredirect=1#comment48592789_30244608)

**--UPDATE--**

AIX ifconfig -a:

```
$ ifconfig -a
en0: flags=1e080863,480<UP,BROADCAST,NOTRAILERS,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPR
T,64BIT,CHECKSUM_OFFLOAD(ACTIVE),CHAIN>
        inet 10.105.65.131 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 10.105.255.255
         tcp_sendspace 262144 tcp_recvspace 262144 rfc1323 1
lo0: flags=e08084b,c0<UP,BROADCAST,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPRT,64
BIT,LARGESEND,CHAIN>
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 broadcast 127.255.255.255
        inet6 ::1%1/0
         tcp_sendspace 131072 tcp_recvspace 131072 rfc1323 1
```

AIX netstat -rn:

```
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables
Destination        Gateway           Flags   Refs     Use  If   Exp  Groups

Route tree for Protocol Family 2 (Internet):
default            10.105.65.1       UG       31  39412125 en0      -      -
10.105.0.0         10.105.65.131     UHSb      0         0 en0      -      -   =
>
10.105/16          10.105.65.131     U       219 985607244 en0      -      -
10.105.65.131      127.0.0.1         UGHS      5   1326738 lo0      -      -
10.105.255.255     10.105.65.131     UHSb      3   6926640 en0      -      -
127/8              127.0.0.1         U        36  11962928 lo0      -      -

Route tree for Protocol Family 24 (Internet v6):
::1%1              ::1%1             UH        1    393270 lo0      -      -
```

I tried `route get` and that doesn't work on my AIX box to tell me the route. The only thing I can get to work is netstat -rn. I'm not sure if there is another command similar to `ip route` that would work.

The Linux boxes support both `ip` and `ifconfig`.

I am not sure what to do when there are multiple network interface cards, as I do not know which one really should be used when setting up a virtual IP.

The Linux setup is more what I am concerned with, as I will be eventually adding in the AIX support for my software installation script later and can do more research on it then.

Comment: AIX is somewhat rare these days. Could you provide samples of `ifconfig` output there? Similarly, it would be helpful to know whether your Linux-based targets support iproute2 (the `ip` command), as modern distributions should, or if the (unmaintained-since-the-mid-90s) `ifconfig` command needs to be used.

Comment: Also -- if there's more than one NIC, which one do you want that data for? The same one used for the default route?

Comment: ...a sample of `netstat -rn` on AIX might also be helpful, if you want answers extended to cover that platform.

Comment: Edited into the question might be better -- comment formatting is pretty awful.

Comment: ...if there's an equivalent command on AIX to `ip route` -- to ask the OS which route it would take to get to a given destination -- that would be good to know as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux, I might do this something like so (using bash extensions, so invoked using a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, or piping the script over stdin to an interpreter invoked as `ssh "$hostname" bash <<'EOF'`):

```
internet_address=8.8.8.8 # read data for the NIC used to route here
dev_re='dev ([^[:space:]]+)($|[[:space:]])'
read default_route < <(ip -o route get "$internet_address")
[[ $default_route =~ $dev_re ]] && devname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a addresses < \
  <(netstat -rn | 
    awk -v dev="$devname" '$8 == dev && ($2 == "0.0.0.0" || $2 == "default") { print $1 }')

# emit this output however you like
printf '%s\n' "$dev_re" "${addresses[@]}"
```

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail what the `dev_re` variable is testing, as well as the `[[ $default =~ $dev_re ]] && devname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` line? When I run this line on my box, the test returns false. And when I try the `readarray addresses` part, it returns readarray not found [No such file or directory].

Comment: I'm still having problems running this. I think it's something in the `dev_re` definition, and the test condition `[[ $default_route =~ $dev_re ]] && devname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`. I printed out some of the intermediate variables, and here's what I get: `default_route` is `8.8.8.8 via 10.105.65.1 dev eth0 src 10.105.65.45 cache mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64`. `devname` and `addresses` are null. Also, the return status of the test condition is false. I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Could you post an example of what this returns on your system so I can see what it's supposed to look like and debug from there?

Comment: (I tested the route-parsing code, but was sloppy 'bout the regex and did that off-the-cuff; apologies there).